# How to select only values for MAX(DATE)

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I have done similar SQL queries in my opinion already before but this is somehow impossible although sounds easy... I hope you can help me in this, I have checked multiple answers for relating questions finding no working solution. I'm using SQL Developer.

I have two tables:

FAMILY

[image]

and FAMILY_PLAN

[image]

And I need to find only the newest FAMILY_PLAN to each person. And the answer should be like this:

[image]

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you post the "Create table" script - are those date colums "date" or "varchar"?

Comment: They are date columns